# Translation: あまり働きすぎないでください。

Tags: negation

This sentence is from the Marugoto chapter on using V+ないで.

I am not sure about the role of あまり - I was told that it adds an extra emphasis? So how do you translate it? ("You really mustn't work too hard"?)

They also have
あまり むりをしないで which I find equally difficult to translate. ("You really mustn't overdo it"?)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When used as an adverb, あまり has two definitions. In addition to the "not very much" meaning that is restricted to negative sentences, it can also mean "too much" or "excessively", which is the meaning used here. に or にも is often attached when used like this.

The すぎる pattern already conveys the idea of "too much" in the first sentence, so adding あまり simply doubles down on that. That is probably why you were told it adds emphasis. Removing it wouldn't change the meaning of the sentence.

> あまり働きすぎないでください。
>   Please don't work too much (hard).

Your second sentence is essentially the same, but the "too much" is conveyed solely by あまり.

> あまり無理をしないで。
>   Don't push yourself too hard.